# Kerberos test using kinit with no password (cert auth)

Tags: kerberos, x509

I did extensive search before posting this Q.

We have a Kerb setup working fine for most users for our internal portal. For a few users we are getting the following error:

> "Failed to create delegated GSSAPI token on behalf of
> HTTP/ssologon.xxx.xxx.xx.com@XXX.XXX.XX.COM for
> service@hostname.xxx.xxx.xx.com: Minor Status=-1765328230, Major
> Status=851968, Message=Cannot find KDC for requested realm]"

I can test kerb setup fine from the Server side using Kinit using Keytab file etc.

Issue/Q is how do I test the same from the workstations/client PC which are exhibiting the above error.

I could use kinit or kinit principal-name but it prompts for a Password. But we have disabled Passwords authentication and use X509 certs/Access Card to login to our PCs/Domain.

> So, how do we use Kinit or equiv. to test kerberos from a domain workstation
> using CLI and Cert authentication.

I have seen the kinit -X option but it is not available on JDK1.7/1.8 in Win 7  it seems. Is pkinit (MIT Kerberos) an option but it seems more like used for web server to KDC authentication.

Thank you in advance and appreciate the community's time and effort.

---- Additional Info 1----

Btw, had the user purge all his tickets - klist purge and had her try accessing the SSO site (protected using IWA Kerb) and verified she is issued a kerb ticket

> ## 5     Client: xxjdoe @ XXX.XX.XXX
>
> ```
>     Server: HTTP/ssologon.xxx.xxx.xx.xx @ XXX.XXX.XX.XXX
>     KerbTicket Encryption Type: RSADSI RC4-HMAC(NT)
>     Ticket Flags 0x40a40000 -> forwardable renewable pre_authent ok_as_delegate
>     Start Time: 4/7/2017 13:54:59 (local)
>     End Time:   4/7/2017 23:54:48 (local)
>     Renew Time: 4/14/2017 13:54:48 (local)
>     Session Key Type: RSADSI RC4-HMAC(NT)
> ```

-------- End 1 ---------------

Comment: That error message is referenced in http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-4557/trouble-6/index.html >> could be a cross-domain AD issue. If `ssologon.xxx.xxx.xx.com` and `hostname.xxx.xxx.xx.com` are not mapped to the same AD domain (i.e. the same Kerberos realm) then `krb5.conf` needs to explain how delegation works, explicitly (cf. `[capath]`) or implicitly (i.e. you have 2 realms `FOO.DUH.COM` and `BAR.DUH.COM` plus the root `DUH.COM` used as gateway)

Comment: Of course, using a Microsoft client -- or anything that relies on SSPI -- you will never get any error message about GSSAPI, so I assume that error comes from a Linux utility (or a Java utility on Windows).

Comment: Thanks but the setup is working fine for most users. What could be different in their setup/profile. Yes, we use a Siteminder Agent plugin on IIS which handles Kerb Auth. It is written in C, but I think it relies on JNI and Java for Kerb libraries. Also please refer to the original post for new information towards the end.